# How do I use Jquery Validate to validate a password but not require it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am wondering if anyone has used the Jquery Validate Password plugin ( http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-password-validation/) to validate passwords but not require them.

In my case,  I am putting together an edit user form. A user cannot exist without having a password. So when an admin is editing a user, I know that a password has already been validated and assigned to the user.

I want the Admin to be able to submit the form and leave the password fields blank. This means that the password was not changed. But, if the admin does want to change the password, I want to use jquery validate password (linked above) to validate the password.

In my html `<head>`, I have:

```
<script src="/Scripts/Common/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Common/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Common/jquery-validate.password/jquery.validate.password.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/Scripts/Common/jquery-validate.password/jquery.validate.password.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#edit").validate();
        $("#password").valid();
    });
</script>
```

and in the `form` field (in Razor and MVC syntax):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "edit" })) { 
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserAccount.UserAccountId)

    <!-- other user fields removed for brevity -->

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Password</th>
            <td>
                @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { id="password", @class="password"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="password-meter">
                    <div class="password-meter-message"> </div>
                    <div class="password-meter-bg">
                        <div class="password-meter-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p>
        <button type="submit">Save</button> @Html.ActionLink("Nevermind", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

This works great. Though it requires a password to be entered. Can I modify it to not require the password and only validate it?

Comment: just wondering here `/Scripts/Common/jquery.js` you loading the minified jquery or standard? should usually have `jquery.min.js` (just a side comment)

Comment: Yes... I believe it is minified. I just typed that in quick for this post as that link is in the masterpage and I was copying from the view. :-)

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
$("#edit_form").validate({
    rules: {
        re_password: {
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        re_password: {
            equalTo: "Password does not match"
        }
    }
});
```

without use class "required" in input field

```
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="TextBox">
<input id="re_password" type="password" name="re_password" class="TextBox">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#edit").validate(
           rules: {
              password: { required: false }
           },
        );
        $("#password").valid();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It did not work unfortunately. I think it's  part of the Password plugin and it's getting hung up on the password not being long enough. (btw: your code sample is missing curly brackets around rules)